# How to modify the content in the class file, this class has many references？

Tags: java

I now want to modify a piece of logic code in the class file in a jar file, but this file has many references. The java file decompiled using JDGUI cannot be used. What do I need to do to modify the code in the class file directly?

Comment: copy the decompiled code to java file, add the jar file in the classpath, make changes to java file, compile and replace it in jar file

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps

- Copy the decompiled code to java file, name same as the class name,
- Set classpath, add the jar file in the classpath
- Make required changes to java file
- Compile the java file using `javac`
- Replace generated class file in jar file